# ¿Calcular Vacaciones tomando encuenta la reforma actual y la reforma anterior en méxico en php?

Tags: javascript, sql, php7

Tengo un listado de usuarios que tienen una fecha de ingreso. Según la reforma anterior por cada año trabajado se aumentan 2 en los primeros años, pero después de 5-9 se aumentan 14 y de 10-14 se aumentan 16 y así sucesivamente. Ejemplo si un usuario ingreso el 09-09-2017, el cálculo de Vacaciones seria 36 días de vacaciones con la reforma anterior y 42 días con la reforma actual.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código calcula las vacaciones antes de la reforma actual. Pero he realizado varios códigos para calcular las vacaciones con la reforma actual pero no me da el resultado esperado en el ejemplo.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Porque complicaste tanto el codigo?? para que sirve el for? con poner directamente el numero, alcanza, no tenes que andar sumando nada...  por ejemplo, para 6 años, son 14 dias mas los que tenia antes, o son 14 dias?

Comment: el bucle "for" se utiliza para calcular los días de vacaciones para un empleado en función de su antigüedad en la empresa. El bucle itera a lo largo de los años de antigüedad del empleado y realiza diferentes cálculos para diferentes rangos de años.

Answer (score 0):

mira no tengo mucho conocimiento en PHP ya que he dejado de desarrollar software en ese lenguaje, pero te dejo este trigger MySQL que acabo
de programar por que también estoy haciendo lo mismo que tu. Para tu software o modulo de las vacaciones de acuerdo a la nueva reforma laboral mexicana de las vacaciones lo puedes integrar.

El trigger funciona así:

Se calculan los años de antigüedad del colaborador tomando en cuenta dos datos que es la fecha en que ingreso el personal y la fecha actual, de ahi se toma la diferencia de estas fechas y se calcula los años trabajados.

Según los años trabajados, le tocan al trabajador N cantidad de días de vacaciones.

Ese N cantidad de días le corresponden a un periodo o año.

Espero y te sirva.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER YOUR_DATABASE.asignar_vacaciones
BEFORE INSERT ON tu_tabla_trabajadores
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE antiguedad INT; -- VARIABLE AÑOS DE TRABAJO TIPO ENTERO
DECLARE dias_vacaciones INT; -- VARIABLE DIAS DE VACACIONES TIPO ENTERO
DECLARE anho_actual INT; -- VARIABLE ANHO ACTUAL TIPO ENTERO

-- Calcular los anhos de antiguedad en funcion de la diferencia de años de 
la FECHA DE CONTRATACION y la FECHA ACTUAL y guardarlo en la variable 
antiguedad
SET antiguedad = TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, NEW.fecha_contratacion, CURDATE());
-- Extraer el año actual y guardarlo en la variable anho_actual para 
referenciar que ese 
SET anho_actual = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURDATE());

-- Calcular días de vacaciones según la antigüedad y guardarlo en la 
-- variable dias_vacaciones
CASE
    WHEN antiguedad = 1 THEN SET dias_vacaciones = 12;
    WHEN antiguedad = 2 THEN SET dias_vacaciones = 14;
    WHEN antiguedad = 3 THEN SET dias_vacaciones = 16;
    WHEN antiguedad = 4 THEN SET dias_vacaciones = 18;
    WHEN antiguedad = 5 THEN SET dias_vacaciones = 20;
    WHEN antiguedad BETWEEN 6 AND 10 THEN SET dias_vacaciones = 22;
    WHEN antiguedad BETWEEN 11 AND 15 THEN SET dias_vacaciones = 24;
    WHEN antiguedad BETWEEN 16 AND 20 THEN SET dias_vacaciones = 26;
    WHEN antiguedad BETWEEN 21 AND 25 THEN SET dias_vacaciones = 28;
    WHEN antiguedad BETWEEN 26 AND 30 THEN SET dias_vacaciones = 30;
    WHEN antiguedad BETWEEN 31 AND 36 THEN SET dias_vacaciones = 32;
    ELSE SET dias_vacaciones = 0; -- Otra antigüedad no asigna días
END CASE;

-- Actualizar el campo de días de vacaciones y periodo
-- si el mes y dia de la FECHA DE CONTRATACION es igual al mes y dia de la 
-- FECHA ACTUAL

IF(EXTRACT(DAY FROM NEW.fecha_contratacion) = EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURDATE()) 
AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM NEW.fecha_contratacion) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURDATE())
)
THEN
-- ACTUALIZA la cantidad de vacaciones y el periodo o anho actual
SET NEW.cantidad_dias_vacaciones = dias_vacaciones, 
    NEW.Periodo_o_anho = anho_actual;
END IF;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: No es tan bueno guardar cálculos, sobre todo si son resultado de una [*función determinista*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_determinista) que puede consistir en un puñado de operaciones básicas.